# jQuery: Extract the text from a div and put it in paragraphs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div like this:

```
<div id="slidecaption"> Some text here. Some other text </div>
```

I want to extract the text from that div until I reach that "." and put it in a new paragraph and the text after "." in another paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery [`html(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) and iterate an array split by dot.

```js
$('#slidecaption').html(function(_, existing) {
  return existing.trim().split('.').map(function(txt) {
    return txt.length ? $('<p>').text(txt + '.') : '';
  });
});
```

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slidecaption">Some text here. Some other text.</div>
```

Assumes that the only dots will be periods at end of sentences

Comment: Great job! It helped me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use the html() function of the selected object to grab the inner HTML content.
Then, assuming consistent formatting, you can split the content into a list (separating either by "." or ". "), iterate through that list. Finally, use jQuery's "append" method to put the content wherever you want it to be.

Note: If the content is not consistent (eg. a second period, or nested HTML) then this might require modification. But for the example you provided, it should work fine.

```
var inner_content = $("#slidecaption").html()
var content_parts = inner_content.split(".");
for(idx in content_parts){
  new_content = "<p>" + content_parts[idx] + "</p>";
  inner_content.append(new_content) // Or wherever else you want to put it
};
```